# Open Distro for Elasticsearch on-prem Kubernetes issues

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elasticsearch-opendistro, bare-metal-server

I'm attempting to setup an open distro for elasticsearch cluster on an on-prem kubernetes cluster. I'm using https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/opendistro-build/tree/master/helm with mostly default values.

The only thing changed in the values.yaml is the nodeSelector and storageClass sections.

```
# This applies to the master, data, client, and kibana nodes
nodeSelector:
  kubernetes.io/hostname: node-1
# This applies to the master and data nodes.
storageClass: elasticsearch-test # master node
storageClass: elasticsearch-data-test # data node
size: 30Gi
```

If I attempt to uncomment any of the items under config, all the pods go into a crash loop:

```
  config:
    ## Example Config
    #opendistro_security.allow_unsafe_democertificates: true
    #opendistro_security.allow_default_init_securityindex: true
    #opendistro_security.audit.type: internal_elasticsearch
    #opendistro_security.enable_snapshot_restore_privilege: true
    #opendistro_security.check_snapshot_restore_write_privileges: true
    #cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
    #opendistro_security.audit.config.disabled_rest_categories: NONE
    #opendistro_security.audit.config.disabled_transport_categories: NONE
    #cluster:
    #  name: elasticsearch
    #node:
    # master: ${NODE_MASTER}
    # data: ${NODE_DATA}
    # name: ${NODE_NAME}
    # ingest: ${NODE_INGEST}
    # max_local_storage_nodes: 1
    # attr.box_type: hot
    # processors: ${PROCESSORS:1}
    # network.host: ${NETWORK_HOST}
    # thread_pool.bulk.queue_size: 800

    #path:
      # data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      # logs: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs

    #http:
    # enabled: true
    # compression: true

    #discovery:
    # zen:
    #   ping.unicast.hosts: []
    #   minimum_master_nodes: 1

    # TLS Configuration Transport Layer
    #opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: elk-transport-crt.pem
    #opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: elk-transport-key.pem
    #opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: elk-transport-root-ca.pem
    #opendistro_security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false

    # # TLS Configuration REST Layer
    #opendistro_security.ssl.http.enabled: true
    #opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: elk-rest-crt.pem
    #opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: elk-rest-key.pem
    #opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: elk-rest-root-ca.pem
```

The pods:

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE
opendistro-es-client-84c788dd7d-z8sf5   1/1     Running   0          7m56s   10.0.0.166   node-1
opendistro-es-data-0                    1/1     Running   0          7m56s   10.0.0.171   node-1
opendistro-es-kibana-576f4577f9-fwthz   1/1     Running   0          7m56s   10.0.0.167   node-1
opendistro-es-master-0                  1/1     Running   0          7m56s   10.0.0.172   node-1
```

Services:

```
NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
kubernetes                     ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP
opendistro-es-client-service   ClusterIP   10.109.25.235    <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP,9600/TCP,9650/TCP
opendistro-es-data-svc         ClusterIP   None             <none>        9300/TCP,9200/TCP,9600/TCP,9650/TCP
opendistro-es-discovery        ClusterIP   None             <none>        9300/TCP
opendistro-es-kibana-svc       ClusterIP   10.106.173.211   <none>        443/TCP
```

The errors in the opendistro-es-data-0 pod:

```
[2020-11-11T00:19:05,035][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [opendistro-es-data-0] master not discovered yet: have discovered [{opendistro-es-data-0}{e_r9yR9_RDidZINEgKxYUA}{ubDNKWVLSJ2q1SIu59NVMQ}{10.0.0.171}{10.0.0.171:9300}{dr}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [] from last-known cluster state; node term 8, last-accepted version 17 in term 8
[2020-11-11T00:19:07,073][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [opendistro-es-data-0] timed out after [5s] resolving host [opendistro-es-discovery]
[2020-11-11T00:19:07,082][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [opendistro-es-data-0] failed to resolve host [opendistro-es-discovery]
java.net.UnknownHostException: opendistro-es-discovery
        at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:886) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1495) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1354) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1288) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:548) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:490) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:855) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.SeedHostsResolver.lambda$resolveHostsLists$0(SeedHostsResolver.java:144) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:651) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

The client pod throws the same "failed to resolve host [opendistro-es-discovery]" error.

The elasticsearch.yml in opendistro-es-master-0:

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

# # minimum_master_nodes need to be explicitly set when bound on a public IP
# # set to 1 to allow single node clusters
# # Details: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17288
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

# # Breaking change in 7.0
# # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_discovery_changes
# cluster.initial_master_nodes:
#    - elasticsearch1
#    - docker-test-node-1
######## Start OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Demo Configuration ########
# WARNING: revise all the lines below before you go into production
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
opendistro_security.ssl.http.enabled: true
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.allow_unsafe_democertificates: true
opendistro_security.allow_default_init_securityindex: true
opendistro_security.authcz.admin_dn:
  - CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test, C=de

opendistro_security.audit.type: internal_elasticsearch
opendistro_security.enable_snapshot_restore_privilege: true
opendistro_security.check_snapshot_restore_write_privileges: true
opendistro_security.restapi.roles_enabled: ["all_access", "security_rest_api_access"]
opendistro_security.system_indices.enabled: true
opendistro_security.system_indices.indices: [".opendistro-alerting-config", ".opendistro-alerting-alert*"]
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3
######## End OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Demo Configuration ########
```

When I run "curl -XGET https://localhost:9200 -u admin:admin --insecure" inside the master pod, I get the response "Open Distro Security not initialized."

When I run "./plugins/opendistro_security/tools/securityadmin.sh -cd ../securityconfig/ -icl -nhnv inside the master pod -cacert ../../../config/root-ca.pem -cert ../../../config/kirk.pem -key ../../../config/kirk-key.pem" it just times out.

Seems to me the nodes are unable to see each other but I don't know how to fix it. As I mentioned before, using the config section in the values.yaml causes all the pods to break. If you happen to know how to fix that and/or this issue, that would be amazing. Please let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue didn't have to do with open distro or kubernetes, it was an issue with the way calico was installed and configured that was messing with the pod DNS.

Comment: Please, would you share more details of the issue with calico and the way to resolve? I have similar problem on microk8s.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer and posted it.

Answer (score 0):

In local environments, it is a matter of specific setup that may be required. See [github ES helm repo](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch#how-to-deploy-this-chart-on-a-specific-k8s-distribution) for more info.